# AngularJS adding controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-directive, angular-template, angular-controller

I am building up a single page website using MEAN, I've tried multiple tutorials and googled a lot of examples but i cant seem to get it working.
i am using `angular-routing` for my templates, but when I add a controller - the templates is not showing. Not any error.

app.js

```
angular.module('sampleApp', ['frontPageCtrl','ngRoute', 'appRoutes']);
```

appRoutes.js

```
angular.module('appRoutes', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider 

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'frontController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

frontPageController.js

```
angular.module('frontPageCtrl', [])
.controller('frontController', function($scope, $http) {
});
```

In my `index.html` file I have included all three files with `app.js` first and after angular include.

**EDIT:**

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<base href="/">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/frontPage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/"

<!-- JS -->
<script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/frontPageController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="frontController">
<div id="container">

<div id="content">
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a plnkr so others can help more easliy

Comment: plnkr? @NitsanBaleli

Comment: is frontController as a variable - available in that file where you have $routeProvider ? then use frontController - without quotes (!)

Comment: Can you show your index.html file?

Comment: @codeninja.sj added my index file

Comment: @user2798413, Don't use same controller for template and index file; create separate controller for it

Comment: Try first put all JS angular code into one file. if problem is solved then it's an file order issue

Comment: Refer my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453718/unknown-provider-error-angularjs-app-issue/35457340#35457340

Answer (score 2):

Things to check

1. Have you added ng-view in ur main landing page
2. Have you addedd ng-app="sampleApp" in main landing page.
3. Put break point in controller just to make sure it gets in there
4. Check network tab and make sure all javascript files are loading

And don't forget to mark it as an answer if this answers ur question :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see after viewing your code, your dependency injection is wrong. See the changes in `appRoutes.js`, `app.js` ,`index.html` and you need `home.html` with `frontController` inside your `views` folder.

Your app.js should be:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []);
```

Your appRoutes.js should be:

```
    angular.module('sampleApp', ['frontPageCtrl','ngRoute', 'sampleApp'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider 

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'frontController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });


        }]);
```

And Your frontPageController.js:

```
    angular.module('frontPageCtrl', [])
    .controller('frontController', function($scope, $http) {
    });
```

And, In your Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <base href="/">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/frontPage.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/"
      <!-- JS -->
      <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/frontPageController.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="sampleApp">
      <div id="container">
         <div id="content">
            <div ng-view></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And, Your `home.html` should have the controller `frontController`. By default, your `home.html` will take the `frontController`, if `ng-controller="frontController"` not used.

```
<div ng-controller="frontController">
```

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ohe4U0Am83U5Hj05HOIv?p=preview

Comment: Tried this and still nothing

Comment: let me edit it, you were missing your index, thats why i assumed and posted it.

Comment: still not working, i even tried putting all my angular code in the same file as shershen commented on original post.

Comment: check out the plunker , its working, plunker link is at the bottom of my answer. If you checked your console. $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present.

Comment: Where did you put the <base> tag? dont see it in the plunker

Comment: Before using <base> tag, you have to learn about the base tag, its advantages and disadvantages.The topic of understanding <base> tag is a question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag refer it to understand.